# CakePHP Pagination 'conditions' limited by $this->Session->read()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm trying to limit my pagination results by the $this->Session->read('Player.team_id')... so that the logged in user can only see his related team members.

PlayersController.php

```
public $paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(
                'Player.team_id' => $this->Session->read('Player.0.Team.id')
             ),
    'limit' => 20,
    'order' => array('Player.fullname' => 'asc')
);

public function index() {
        $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
        $this->Player->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('players', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }
```

This causes an error when viewing player/index

Error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE
File: /home/www/public_html/dev/app/Controller/PlayersController.php
Line: 21

If I hardcode the 'conditions' as below then it works fine and only retrieves the records I want

```
'conditions' => array('Player.team_id' => 1)
```

In the Player.php model login action it writes the Session Variable Team.id and Team.name.

I have used the $this->Session->read else where in my app (views and other models) and it works fine. It just doesn't seem to work with in the pagination component?

Comment: Are you using session component? Also what code is on line 21?

Comment: Yes the session component is being loaded in the AppController.php file.

Comment: Line 21: 'Player.team_id' => $this->Session->read('Player.0.Team.id')

It's having the issue with $this->Session->read('Player.0.Team.id') because if I replace it "1" then the code works.

Comment: try `$pid= $this->Session->read('Player.0.Team.id');` and check by echoing its value, also `'Player.team_id' =>$pid`

Comment: @Nouphal.M Thanks, I tried that but the error now appears on the line where I place this code. I even tried AuthComponent::user('Player.team_id') but it causes the same problem.

Comment: is it a valid session key `Player.0.Team.id`. try printing your session

Comment: Try some thing like $this->Session->write('Playerone.Teamid',$value); And $this->Session->read('Playerone.Teamid')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply invalid PHP syntax, class members can only be initialized with constant values, that is values that can be evaluated at compile time (strings, numbers, booleans, arrays, etc...)

Assign the session value at runtime in the [**`Controller::beforeFilter()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3abeforeFilter) callback (or even directly in the `index()` action in case appropriate) instead:

```
public $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 20,
    'order' => array('Player.fullname' => 'asc')
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->paginate['conditions'] = array(
        'Player.team_id' => $this->Session->read('Player.0.Team.id')
    );
}
```

Also as pointed out in the comments, make sure that the session key you are accessing actually exists and holds the expected value!

See also **http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php**